# Rewriting a htaccess condition with 2 parameters on url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to show better nice url format using 2 parameters, I got this

```
http://example.com/job.php?page=4045
```

and I obtaining this format,

```
 http://example.com/4045/job
```

using this htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\job$ job.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\job$ job.php?page=$1
```

and is working but I would like two parameters on the url like this,

```
http://example.com/job.php?page=4045&page1=5055
```

I tried this,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\job$ job.php?page=$1&page1=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\job$ job.php?page=$1&page1=$1
```

but didn't work, any help?

Comment: your rule is actually going in the wrong direction.  you want to take `http://fool.com/myfolder/1233-this-cool/product` and turn it into `http://fool.com/myfolder/product?page=1233&page1=this&page2=cool` so that your site can function as it currently does.

Comment: Set `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` and mod_rewrite will tell you exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @cmorrissey yes, but in this case I would like with two parameters, http://example.com/job.php?page=4045&page1=5055